# Node.js(Express.js, Sequelize-cli)' - No database selected' error in Render

Tags: node.js, database, express, sequelize.js

I created a project on Node js(Express js) with sequelize ORM and earlier, I used sequelize-cli to create and migrate database and tables respectively.

this is my package.json:

```
 {
      "name": "library-management",
      "version": "0.0.0",
      "private": true,
      "scripts": {
        "start": "nodemon app.js",
        "install-and-migrate": "npm install && sequelize-cli db:create && sequelize-cli db:migrate"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "bcrypt": "^5.1.1",
        "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
        "express": "^4.18.2",
        "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",
        "nodemon": "^3.0.1",
        "sequelize": "^6.32.1",
        "sequelize-cli": "^6.6.1"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "mysql2": "^3.6.0"
      }
    }
```

and this is my config.js file after changing it from config.json:

```
    const dotenv = require('dotenv');
    dotenv.config();
    
    const config = {
      dialect: process.env.DB_DIALECT || "mysql",
      host: process.env.DB_HOST || "127.0.0.1",
      port: process.env.DB_PORT || 3306,
      username: process.env.DB_USERNAME || "root",
      password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    };
    
    // console.log(config);
    
    module.exports = {
      url: process.env.DB_CONNECTION_URL,
      development: { ...config, database: process.env.DB_DEVELOPMENT_NAME },
      test: { ...config, database: process.env.DB_TEST_NAME },
      production: { ...config, database: process.env.DB_PROD_NAME },
    };
```

and
.sequelizerc:

```
 const path = require('path');
    
    module.exports = {
      'config': path.resolve('config', 'config.js'),
      'models-path': path.resolve('models'),
    //   'seeders-path': path.resolve('seeders'),
      'migrations-path': path.resolve('migrations')
    };

and my app.js:

    require('dotenv').config();
    const express = require('express');
    const app = express()
    const userRoutes = require("./routes/userRoutes")
    const adminRoutes = require("./routes/adminRoutes")
    const bookRoutes = require("./routes/bookRoutes")
    const authorRoutes = require("./routes/authorRoutes")
    
    app.use(express.json())
    
    app.use('/users',userRoutes)
    app.use('/book',bookRoutes)
    app.use('/author',authorRoutes)
    app.use('/admin',adminRoutes)
    
    app.listen(3000);
```

When I started the deployment operation, it showed me that:

```
 Nov 23 10:46:38 AM  Sequelize CLI [Node: 14.17.0, CLI: 6.6.2, ORM: 6.35.1]
    Nov 23 10:46:38 AM  
    Nov 23 10:46:38 AM  Loaded configuration file "config/config.js".
    Nov 23 10:46:38 AM  Using environment "development".
    Nov 23 10:46:41 AM  Database bzkjl4pacusbj3w7ymkv created.
    Nov 23 10:46:41 AM  
    Nov 23 10:46:41 AM  Sequelize CLI [Node: 14.17.0, CLI: 6.6.2, ORM: 6.35.1]
    Nov 23 10:46:41 AM  
    Nov 23 10:46:41 AM  Loaded configuration file "config/config.js".
    Nov 23 10:46:41 AM  Using environment "development".
    Nov 23 10:46:44 AM  No migrations were executed, database schema was already up to date.
```

But when I started inserting the endpoints using PostMan, it's telling me that:

```
    Nov 23 12:43:37 PM
  original: Error: No database selected
Nov 23 12:43:37 PM
      at Packet.asError (/opt/render/project/src/Server/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packets/packet.js:728:17)
Nov 23 12:43:37 PM
      at Query.execute (/opt/render/project/src/Server/node_modules/mysql2/lib/commands/command.js:29:26)
Nov 23 12:43:37 PM
      at Connection.handlePacket (/opt/render/project/src/Server/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:478:34)
Nov 23 12:43:37 PM
      at PacketParser.onPacket (/opt/render/project/src/Server/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:97:12)
Nov 23 12:43:37 PM
      at PacketParser.executeStart (/opt/render/project/src/Server/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packet_parser.js:75:16)
Nov 23 12:43:37 PM
      at Socket.<anonymous> (/opt/render/project/src/Server/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:104:25)
Nov 23 12:43:37 PM
      at Socket.emit (events.js:376:20)
Nov 23 12:43:37 PM
      at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:309:12)
Nov 23 12:43:37 PM
      at readableAddChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:284:9)
Nov 23 12:43:37 PM
      at Socket.Readable.push (internal/streams/readable.js:223:10) {
Nov 23 12:43:37 PM
    code: 'ER_NO_DB_ERROR',
Nov 23 12:43:37 PM
    errno: 1046,
Nov 23 12:43:37 PM
    sqlState: '3D000',
Nov 23 12:43:37 PM
    sqlMessage: 'No database selected',
Nov 23 12:43:37 PM
    sql: 'SELECT `id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `role`, `username`, `email`, `password`, `age`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt` FROM `Users` AS `User`;',
Nov 23 12:43:37 PM
    parameters: undefined
Nov 23 12:43:37 PM
  },
Nov 23 12:43:37 PM
  sql: 'SELECT `id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `role`, `username`, `email`, `password`, `age`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt` FROM `Users` AS `User`;',
Nov 23 12:43:37 PM
  parameters: {}
Nov 23 12:43:37 PM
}
```

I have shared my concerns in their community room but I still cannot figure out whether is this happening from my side or from theirs.

because its still working in the localhost.

I am using cleaver-cloud to create a mysql add-on so that I can create a live database.